# How can I use my CC Libraries colours in Photoshop CC Color Swatches?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, creative-cloud

I created a Color CC Library but I can't use it when I need to pick one of these colours for a gradient. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Double Click on the color in your library panel
- Choose Add to Swatches

Then they'll function like any other Swatch

Comment: Yep that worked... it is not quite explanatory by the app. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

open the libraries tab (make sure it's enabled under 'window') and find the colour theme in question. from there clicking the colours will select them as the primary colour. you can then press 'x' to move that to the background colour and select the other colour for the gradient (presumably from the same theme, simply by clicking the colour)